# extract value from a list netmiko , python3, f5

Tags: python, list, python-re, f5, netmiko

Please could someone help me to guide how to extract value from the below OUTPUT.

```
**print(k)**
HOST-ABC01
['1']
['1']
['2']
['3']
['4']
```

I need to store last digit in the last line of the output. Example from above , I need to have 4 store in slotnum.

slotnum = 4

My code is here below:

```
import re  
from netmiko import Netmiko 
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import time  

f_2 = open("f5ips.txt","r") # You should open a notepad with this name and add all the IPs one under the other.
multiple_device_list = f_2.readlines()
#print(multiple_device_list)

# create lists 
name = []

def _slot_(nodeip):
    try:
        switch = {
            'device_type': 'f5_ltm', 'ip': nodeip, 'username':
            'user', 'password':"pass", "conn_timeout": 2}
        switch_connect = Netmiko(**switch)
        print(nodeip.strip() + " " + "is reachable")
        prompt_sw_axa = switch_connect.find_prompt()
        slice1 = (prompt_sw_axa.split(')')[0])
        slice2 = [slice1.split("(")[1]]
        name = [(slice2[0])]
        print(name)
        
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        'f_2.write(nodeip.strip() + "\n")'
        return

    output = switch_connect.send_command ("show sys cluster field-fmt")    
    print(name[0]) 
    LINES = output.split("\n")
    #print(LINES)
    search_strg1 = "slot-id"

    for l1 in LINES:
        if re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(search_strg1), l1):
            k = [([l1][0][-1])]
            print(k)
        # I need to store last digit in the last line of the output **(NEED HELP HERE)**

        
    switch_connect.disconnect() 

myPool = ThreadPool(100) # you can increase or decrease this value
```

OUTPUT of above script as below:

```
10.10.10.1 is reachable
10.10.10.2 is reachable
['HOST-ABC01']
['HOST-ABC01']
HOST-ABC01
['1']
['1']
['2']
['3']
['4']
HOST-ABC02
['1']
['1']
['2']
['3']
['4']
```

Trying to extract value from K , using re module in python and list to extract but unable to do so.

Comment: `LINES[-1][-1]`?

Comment: LINES contains an output with multiple lines here. Value for K is taken out of this re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(search_strg1), l1): . I need value of K.

Comment: or can someone help how to get last digit in this print(k) "  1
1
2
3
4"

Comment: did you try the command I suggested? What does it give you?